# Angular Material some modules are not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got a problem with Angular Material, some material modules are not working.
One of them is MatInputModule, Webstorm tells me "Class MatInputModule is not an Angular module ".

I deleted my node_modules, after that the error vanished until I run ng serve.
ng serve then compiles all folders inside node_modules/@angular and the error returns.

One of my older projects is working fine with Angular Material but not this one.

My Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, LogoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

All Modules are working fine in this example, just MatInputModule is causing errors.

Hope some one can help me.

Comment: Posting the error and example use of related input component will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finaly, I just forgot to import my module into app.module.

I really don't know why this caused that a lot of angular material modules weren't working and why it told me that it's not a angular module but that solved it.